# Provider is above widget, but flutter can't find it

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

Can't figure it out, please help :(

I'm building mobile app on flutter, using multiprovider.
Other providers work in the whole app fine, but this specific provider "Order" works only in DeliveryPage widget for some reason. I just add
`Order order = context.watch<Order>();` in any other widget and get this error:

> Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this ProductPage Widget
> This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
> of your choice. There are a few common scenarios: ...

I'm preeeetty sure my MultiProvider wraps everything just fine (or isn't it?). Here's devtools screenshot: https://prnt.sc/RRwr3wbX49fN

I've checked for any major differences in DeliveryPage and any other pages and found none. I even compared with ProductPage that is very similar, it is also pushed to Navigator pages array the same way:    `Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: false).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) =>ProductPage()));` but Order provider works fine on DeliveryPage and throws error on ProductPage.

Thank you.

MAIN.DART:

````
import '/provider/mainscreen.dart';
import '/provider/skin.dart';
import '/provider/catalog.dart';
import '/provider/lang.dart';
import '/provider/order.dart';
import '/provider/data.dart';



void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await UserSettings.Load();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return
      MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (context) => Data()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (context) => UserCardi()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (context) => Skin()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (context) => Catalog()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (context) => Order()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (context) => Lang()),

          ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (context) => MainScreen()),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'CARDOIT',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          localizationsDelegates: [
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
          ],
          supportedLocales: [
            Locale('en', ''),
            Locale('ru', ''),
            Locale('de', ''),
            Locale('us', ''),
          ],
          localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
            if (locale != null && supportedLocales.contains(Locale(locale.languageCode))) {
              return locale;
            } else {
              return const Locale('en', '');
            }
          },
          theme: ThemeData(
            brightness: Brightness.light,
            canvasColor: Colors.transparent,
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            fontFamily: "Montserrat",
          ),

          home: WindowMain(),
          /*
          initialRoute: '/',
          routes: MainScreen.routeBuilders(),
          */
        )
      );

  }
}
class WindowMain extends StatelessWidget{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // сразу опередяем язык пользователя
    UserSettings.autoLang(context);

    Skin skin = context.watch<Skin>();
    
    print("main build: " + UserSettings.skinCode);

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: MainAppBar(),
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),

            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: skin.bgBar("appbar"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            child: SafeArea(
                child: MainBottomNavbar()
            )
        ),
        body:   Body()

    );
  }

}

class Body extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MainScreen mainScreen = context.watch<MainScreen>();
    return mainScreen.widgetOptions[mainScreen.index];
  }
}

class MainBottomNavbar extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MainScreen mainScreen = context.watch<MainScreen>();
    Skin skin = context.watch<Skin>();
    return LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                double iconWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4;
                double minHeightIcon = iconWidth * 0.67;

                return Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      width: iconWidth,
                      child: IconButton(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: minHeightIcon,),
                          icon: Image(
                            image: skin.btnIcon("cart", mainScreen.index == 0),
                            width: iconWidth,
                            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () => mainScreen.setWidget(0)),
                    ), Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      width: iconWidth,
                      child: IconButton(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: minHeightIcon,),
                          icon: Image(
                            image: skin.btnIcon(
                                "favorites", mainScreen.index == 1),
                            width: iconWidth,
                            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                          ),
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          onPressed: () => mainScreen.setWidget(1)),
                    ), Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      width: iconWidth,
                      child: IconButton(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: minHeightIcon,),
                          icon: Image(
                            image: skin.btnIcon("cart", mainScreen.index == 2),
                            width: iconWidth,
                            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                          ),
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          onPressed: () => mainScreen.setWidget(2)
                      ),
                    ),
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        width: iconWidth,
                        child: IconButton(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                            constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: minHeightIcon,),
                            icon: Image(
                              image: skin.btnIcon(
                                  "profile", mainScreen.index == 3),
                              width: iconWidth,
                              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                            ),
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            onPressed:
                                () => mainScreen.setWidget(3)
                        ),
                      ),

                    ]);
              }
          );
  }

} ```
````

Comment: I don't see the `context.watch<Order>();`part. Maybe the context you used to get the provider does not include the Navigator ?

Comment: Where do you call the pages? Are they passed in from your `MainScreen` bloc?

Comment: @FPerroch it's in a different file, where ProductPage or DeliveryPage are located. How is it possible though? context is taken at every widget's build method in every widget...

Comment: @Bellrampion in Main.dart there's custom Body widget. It returns 1 of 4 widgets from MainScreen provider, depending on which one is chosen in MainBottomNavbar. (it's some sort of custom navigation we've made for certain reason).

```

class MainScreen with ChangeNotifier {
  int index = 0;

  Map<String, String> map = { "MainPage": "FavoritesPage", "CartPage": "ProfilePage" };

  List<Widget> widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    MainPage(),
    FavoritesPage(),
    CartPage(),
    ProfilePage(),
  ];

  setWidget(int indexCurrent) { ...```

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake.
I started import filename with Uppercase letter, while it actually starts with lowercase. Turns out you can't do that, but AS IDE won't underline it as an error and flutter debug console won't show anything either.